# SQL Server stored procedure troubles

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures, very similar but they return different results!

What I am after is a stored procedure that returns data for a record set in Access.

The first example I have is a simple select using one param which returns what i want BUT doesn't allow me to specify the column to return:

```
EXEC  GetA @ID = '1234';
```

The stored procedure the code above runs against:

```
SELECT 
    column1
FROM 
    tbl_A
WHERE 
    ID = @ID
```

This works fine, it returns the result from the column.. for example some text from the specified cell where ID = @ID.

The second query which i want to work uses a case statement to select which column I need, but instead of returning the 'text' result like the above query, I get an error message stating that it cannot convert the varchar to int for the result.

```
EXEC  GetA @ID = '1234', @columnName = 'column1';
```

Stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN @columnName = 'column1' THEN column1
       WHEN @columnName = 'column2' THEN column2
       WHEN @columnName = 'column3' THEN column3
       WHEN @columnName = 'column4' THEN column4
       WHEN @columnName = 'column5' THEN column5
    END
FROM 
    tbl_A
WHERE 
    ID = @ID
```

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong with the second query please? It should return the exact same result but it seems to be trying to return an INT.. Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Result - Text' to data type int.

UPDATE:

If i only have one 'case' in my statement, for example...WHEN @columnName = 'column1' THEN column1, this returns the text from the cell that i need, however whenever i add more than one case it tries to convert the result from the cell to an INT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single value.  This value must have a type -- only one type is allowed.

SQL (in general) has rather specific rules for determining the return type of a `case` expression.  When there is a mixture of strings and numbers, the return type is a number.  So, all values are converted to a number.  If the conversion fails then you get an error.

In other words, you cannot really do what you want, because the values in the columns have different types.  As a work-around, you could convert all the values to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your SP return value is declared as INT, but your case query does not appear to be an INT.  If it is not going to be an INT need to change it.  I am not sure the max column length in your data so I updated to 50 but you may need to chagne it

```
USE [DB];
GO

DECLARE @return_value varchar(50);

EXEC  @return_value = SelectA 
    @ID = '1234',
    @columnName = 'column1';

SELECT @return_value as N'@Return Value';

GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I gave this a go but it still returns: Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'resulttext' to data type int. I did try setting the return_Value to nvarchar(50) also.

Answer (score 0):

find your inappropriate non integer data and remove it, or try this :

```
SELECT 
CASE
   WHEN @columnName = 'column1' THEN ltrim(rtrim(str(column1)))
   WHEN @columnName = 'column2' THEN ltrim(rtrim(str(column2)))
   WHEN @columnName = 'column3' THEN ltrim(rtrim(str(column3)))
   WHEN @columnName = 'column4' THEN ltrim(rtrim(str(column4)))
   WHEN @columnName = 'column5' THEN ltrim(rtrim(str(column5)))
  END
  FROM  tbl_A WHERE ID = @ID
```